# Issue executing Currentdb.execute in Excel / VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Here is what I am trying to do with excel / access 2007. I have a table in Access. I am trying to create a temporary table to store the results of a query stored in the string strSQL_Insert. However when I try to execute the DoCmd.RunSQL,I get a run time error '424'. "Object required". I tried executing the query itself and getting the results into excel and that seemed to work ok.  Here is what I have

```
Sub GetDataADO()

Dim dbConnection As Object
Dim dbRecordSet  As Object
Dim strSQL As String
Dim dbFileName As String
Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
Dim strTable As String
Dim strSQL_Insert As String

strTable = "tblTempTest"

Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set dbRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

dbFileName = "H:\Unscan.accdb"

dbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
& dbFileName & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

Set DestinationSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

With dbConnection
     .Open
 End With

strSQL_Insert = "INSERT INTO tblTempTest " _
& "SELECT TOP 10 BranchNumber , COUNT(*) as Total FROM BUDetails " _
& "GROUP BY BranchNumber ORDER BY 2 DESC ;"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL_Insert

dbRecordSet.Close
dbConnection.Close

Set dbRecordSet = Nothing
Set dbConnection = Nothing
Set DestinationSheet = Nothing


Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be sure to read the helpful descriptions that pop up when selecting tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this from within Excel, the CurrentDb may not be instantiated.  Try to replace CurrentDB with dbConnection and see if this yields any results.